# Parsing JSON With Codable in Swift

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I am attempting to parse JSON with codable in Swift. I have successfully done this before, but I have a more complicated JSON object with some arrays and I am having trouble.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
"data": [ {
    "type":"player",
    "id":"account.7e5b92e6612440349afcc06b7c390114",
    "attributes": {
        "createdAt":"2018-04-06T04:59:40Z",
        "name":"bob",
        "patchVersion":"",
        "shardId":"pc-na",
        "stats":null,
        "titleId":"bluehole-pubg",
        "updatedAt":"2018-04-06T04:59:40Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "assets": {
            "data":[]
        },
        "matches": {
            "data": [
            {"type":"match","id":"3e2a197a-1453-4569-b35b-99e337dfabc5"},
            {"type":"match","id":"15f41d2f-9da2-4b95-95ca-b85e297e14b7"},
            {"type":"match","id":"a42c496c-ad92-4d3e-af1f-8eaa2e200c2b"}
            {"type":"match","id":"b6e33df5-4754-49da-9a0f-144842bfc306"},
            {"type":"match","id":"5b357cd1-35fe-4859-a2d7-48f263120bbd"},
            {"type":"match","id":"99fc5f81-c24c-4c82-ae03-cd21c94469c0"},
            {"type":"match","id":"1851c88e-6fed-48e8-be84-769f20f5ee6f"},
            {"type":"match","id":"e16db7ea-520f-4db0-b45d-649264ac019c"},
            {"type":"match","id":"6e61a7e7-dcf5-4df5-aa88-89eca8d12507"},
            {"type":"match","id":"dcbf8863-9f7c-4fc9-b87d-93fe86babbc6"},
            {"type":"match","id":"0ba20fbb-1eaf-4186-bad5-5e8382558564"},
            {"type":"match","id":"8b104f3b-66d5-4d0a-9992-fe053ab4a6ca"},
            {"type":"match","id":"79822ea7-f204-47f8-ae6a-7efaac7e9c90"},
            {"type":"match","id":"1389913c-a742-434a-80c5-1373e115e3b6"}
            ]
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "schema":"",
        "self":"https://api.playbattlegrounds.com/shards/pc-na/players/account.7e5b92e6612440349afcc06b7c390114"
    }
}],
"links": {
    "self":"https://api.playbattlegrounds.com/shards/pc-na/players?filter[playerNames]=dchilds64"
    },
"meta":{}
}
```

Here are the models I am using:

```
public struct PlayerResponse: Codable {
    let data: [Player]
}
```

For Player:

```
public struct Player: Codable {
    let type: String
    let id: String
    let attributes: Attributes
    let relationships: Relationships
}
```

For Attributes:

```
public struct Attributes: Codable {
    let name: String
    let patchVersion: String
    let shardId: String
    let titleId: String
    let updatedAt: String
}
```

For Relationships:

```
public struct Relationships: Codable {
    let matches: Matches
}
```

For Matches:

```
public struct Matches: Codable {
    let data: [Match]
}
```

For Match:

```
public struct Match: Codable {
    let type: String
    let id: String

}
```

Decoding as:

```
let players = try decoder.decode([Player].self, from: jsonData)
```

I have this function which runs my network request:

```
    func getPlayerData(for name: String, completion: ((Result<[Player]>) -> Void)?) {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents()
    urlComponents.scheme = "https"
    urlComponents.host = "api.playbattlegrounds.com"
    urlComponents.path = "/shards/\(regionShard.rawValue)/players"
    let playerNameItem = URLQueryItem(name: "filter[playerNames]", value: "\(name)")
    urlComponents.queryItems = [playerNameItem]
    guard let url = urlComponents.url else { fatalError("Could not create URL from components") }
    print(url)

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("bearer \(apiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/vnd.api+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, response, responseError) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = responseError {
                completion?(.failure(error))
            } else if let jsonData = responseData {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                do {
                    let players = try decoder.decode([Player].self, from: jsonData)
                    completion?(.success(players))
                } catch {
                    completion?(.failure(error))
                }
            } else {
                let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Data was not retrieved from request"]) as Error
                completion?(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I get this error when I try to run the network request:

I think there is an issue with my codable structs, but I'm not sure. Could someone point me in the right direction to look for my error?

Comment: I noticed you didn't put a stats var in the attribute struct and also the assets in relationships. but I don't know if that's the whole problem or not.

Comment: *I get this error*. What error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you build this up from the ground, since the errors of `JSONDecoder` (as with any compiler) get worse the more involved your structures are. Let's see how far we get:

Your `Match` struct is pretty sound:

```
public struct Match: Codable {
    let type: String
    let id: String

}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let mData = """
   {"type":"match","id":"3e2a197a-1453-4569-b35b-99e337dfabc5"}
   """.data(using:.utf8)!
let match = try! decoder.decode(Match.self, from:mData)

print(match)
```

No unexpected problems here. Shortening `Matches` a bit you already get your first error, rather an unexpected one

```
public struct Matches: Codable {
    let data: [Match]
}

let mtchsData = """
    {
        "data": [
            {"type":"match","id":"3e2a197a-1453-4569-b35b-99e337dfabc5"},
            {"type":"match","id":"15f41d2f-9da2-4b95-95ca-b85e297e14b7"},
            {"type":"match","id":"a42c496c-ad92-4d3e-af1f-8eaa2e200c2b"}
            {"type":"match","id":"b6e33df5-4754-49da-9a0f-144842bfc306"},
            {"type":"match","id":"5b357cd1-35fe-4859-a2d7-48f263120bbd"}
        ]
    }
    """.data(using:.utf8)!
do {
    let mtches = try decoder.decode(Matches.self, from:mtchsData)
    print(mtches)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

will print the following error:

```
"dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", 
underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
    "Badly formed array around character 233."
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly 
    formed array around character 233.})))\n"
```

This is a trivial error, you are missing a comma on line 3 of the `data` `Array`. Adding that all will go well, but if it comes like this from your service you will have to fix it first.

I guess you get the idea and know your way about building up the structure successively. On the top level you will notice that your top level structure goes beyond an array of `Player`, it is actually a `Dictionary` with `"data"` as its sole key as you modelled correctly in `PlayerResponse` as @AnkitJayaswal pointed out already. That makes two errors already, those are the ones I managed to spot easily, but as I suggested before you should continue the build up of tests, that way you will know that the "lower" levels parse correctly and can concentrate on the problem at hand.

All of the above works easily in a Playground and there is no need to actually call the WebService in the process. Of course you will have to `import Cocoa`, but you already knew that. Anyway it always helps to reduce the level of complexity by splitting up your problem into smaller parts.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It has been really helpful to start looking at the most basic pieces and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your whole player response is in key `data`. And your parsing player info with `Player` codable struct directly rather than `data` key which is used in `PlayerResponse` codable struct.

**To resolve this update your code as:**

```
let players = try decoder.decode(PlayerResponse.self, from: jsonData)
```

Hope this will solve your problem.